# Генерация чпу ссылок

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

Делаю свой сайт на Nuxt.js, сделал пару страниц, но встал вопрос в автоматизации процесса, вот я буду добавлять страницы с материалами, статьи например использующие один шаблон, как мне сделать генерацию путей на уровне автоматизма, чтобы я добавил страницу и ей сразу присвоился адрес, например site.com/articles/what-is-article и поэтому адресу открывается статья.
Как сделать генерацию путей с ЧПУ?